# Refer to an integer from one ViewController from another

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm unable to refer to my integer `pickedItem` declared in my `RootViewController.h` in my `DetailViewController.m` file.

Not sure if I should declare this as a global variable, but tried unsuccessfully to do so.

I think this should be simple, but I haven't got any other suggestions (from other posted answers) to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could we have some code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the app delegate through

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

this call. And then can access the root view controller's property (assuming you have access to the rootViewController object in appDelagate).

In RootViewController.h

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger myInt
```

And from anywhere in the code

```
UIApplicationDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
delegate.viewController.myInt = 31;
```

p.s. I have just typed the code, not compiled. So there might be some typo.

Comment: +1: You can do this or set up a Singleton.  Although many people advocate only putting code in the App Delegate strictly related to handling the application, everyone has their own way of doing things.

Comment: agreed. app delegate and also root view controller should be light weighted as they r always present in the memory and also have effect on staring the app. singleton is good but designing proper singleton is not that easy. i may come up with unnecessary objects in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You just wouldn't want it coded this way. I recommend taking a look at NSNotificationCenter, or create a delegate class for yourself, to communicate to the DetailViewController of page changes.  There shouldn't be a dependency from detail -> root the way you have it.

Based on your code above, I don't see where you're setting rootViewController on detailViewController?  Is it nil?  I'd think referencing rootViewController.pickedItem if rootViewController was nil would cause a crash, but worth checking.

Also, is pickedItem being set appropriately?  In other words, is it set before the detail code is being called?